# Read critical extensions from https certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, x509

I want to do custom validation for node https certificate verification. So, in https options I have set `rejectUnauthorized` property to `false`.

```
var httpsOptions = {
    ...
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ... 
};
```

Now even if certificate verification internally fails, request won't fail. I want to handle that part manually. I wanted to handle `unhandled critical extension` error. My code to do so is,

```
var req = https.request(httpsOptions, (res) => { 
  var data = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
      data += chunk;
  }); 
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

req.on("socket", function () {
  req.socket.on('secureConnect', () => {
    if(!req.socket.authorized){
      if(req.socket.authorizationError === 'unhandled critical extension'){
        // Place to verify extensions
      }
      process.nextTick(() => {req.abort();});      
    }
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(requestObj));
req.end();
```

The above code works as expected. I can say when `unhandled critical extension` error occurs. Inside the `if` condition(Place to verify extensions), I want to see what are all `critical extensions` that are unhandled. If it didn't match the list I have, I want to abort the request. `req.socket` has so many properties, so I could not paste here. There is no field in it, which holds those `unhandled` critical extensions. How to extract the unhandled critical extensions which caused the error?

**Note:** I have seen some `npm` packages which could parse ssl certificates like `x509` and `PKIjs`. It gives lots of confusion and I could not find any working example which can solve my problem.

**EDIT**:

`req.socket.getPeerCertificate().raw` gives the DER certificate in `Buffer` format. How to decode it and view those extensions?

Answer (score 1):

First we need to get the server certificate. We can use `req.socket.getPeerCertificate()` to get it. It returns a JSON object but it won't have extensions section. But, it will be having the entire certificate in `buffer` format in its `raw` property.

```
var certInBuf = req.socket.getPeerCertificate().raw;
```

There are a lot of packages available to convert this buffer format to pem format. One of them is [`pemtools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pemtools)

```
var certInPem = pemtools(certInBuf, 'CERTIFICATE').toString();
```

Then we can use [`node-forge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) to parse the certificate and extract the extensions.

```
var pki = require('node-forge').pki;
var extensions = pki.certificateFromPem(certInPem).extensions;
```

Then we can validate the extensions. If not satisfied we can abort the request by calling `req.abort()`